# Does Agile Scrum methodology use reports

Tags: agile, scrum

> Agile Scrum methodology does not use reports.

Do you agree with this statement?

Can Product Backlog, Sprint Backlog or Sprint Burn Down Charts be considered as reports?

Comment: Providing a generic statement doesn't provide any context. If you took a backlog, burn downs, etc. and handed them off for analysis, they're reports and not just dev team tools.

Comment: Probably what that means is scrum doesn't necessitate formal reporting. The daily stand-ups are a form of reporting but they're generally not formalized into a "report".

Comment: so if I agree to this statement can I show that the above mentioned documents can be used as a form of report?

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: If I accept that Agile Scrum methodology does not use reports, is it acceptable if I say that  Product Backlog, Sprint Backlog or Sprint Burn Down Charts can be considered as reports even though they're not formal reports?

Comment: I'm curious why you would want to do that; seems like you might be in the middle of a flame war. Saying it like that seems contradictory, You can make a logical argument which says those artifacts are "reporting" information; and they do. If they didn't they wouldn't be used. But, if the scrum community believes reports aren't used, your arguments will probably get a *meh* response.

Comment: No no no,this is a part of a question from the Software Engineering1 module I study, and now I get it, the given statement is false since the artifacts are reports(form of reports). Thankyou!!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about project management, not programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Scrum framework was designed from the start to be transparent.

There are three critical components to this:

- A public task board (showing work in progress)
- Sprint reviews (showing achieved progress and open to all stakeholders)

  A public product backlog (showing future work)

It is also worth noting that the Product Owner is the person most interested in this information as they *own* the product. They are involved every day with the team and so have a deep understanding of what is going on.

The issues that occur in Scrum reporting tend to happen due to flaws in the way the Scrum framework has been implemented. For example, if not all interested stakeholders are attending the sprint reviews then there can be misunderstandings. Also, if the Scrum Team is not allowed to be self-organising then there may be some concerns over communication with the technical managers.

Having said that, many teams use reports to *supplement* the Scrum transparency.

The two most common reports are:

- A sprint summary (typically done by the Scrum Master)
- A product update from the Product Owner

Mike Cohn talks about the sprint summary [here](https://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/blog/summarizing-the-results-of-a-sprint).

Product updates have many formats. The most successful ones I have seen are clear and consise summaries of work in progress and planned work that are targetted at people of all levels of technical knowledge (including business users that are non-technical). I have worked with Product Owners that write visually attractive product updates that effectively *market* the Scrum Team to those that do not regularly attend sprint reviews.